# Superset shows internal server error page in sql editor when I'm trying to run it with specific version tag

Tags: apache-superset

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1

I'm trying to follow the official [guide](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose/) how to install superset.

It starts without any problems if I'm using the command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
```

But when I'm trying to do the same with a TAG command (which specifies the exact superset version) I run into problem:

```
git checkout 2.0.0
TAG=2.0.0 docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml pull
TAG=2.0.0 docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
```

The service runs and I can see the correct version 2.0.0 in Settings but I can't visit SQL Editor section anymore. There's page **Internal Server Error** instead of it. And there's an error in server log with an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column report_schedule.extra does not exist
```

I've tried the same with TAG=1.5.0. With absolutely the same result.

Could anyone tell me what can I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade the postgres database schema. As the superset versions grow, the Postgres Schema is constantly changing, and is maintained by superset with the Python Alembic library.

The necessary command:
1.) install "latest" Superset version
2.) superset db downgrade e09b4ae78457
3.) Upgrade (downgrade) Superset to 2.0.0 version

The long identifier is the version of the Postgres Schema of Superset 2.0.0
The current (ex. latest superset) version can be viewed with the following command (by browsing the Postgre database)
select * from alembic_version;

and you can see the superset db changes history with following command:
superset db history

Best regards,
W. L.